# Check all employees who followed two certain courses SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a SQL statement where i can see what employee has followed two certain courses. But i'm not sure how to do this in SQL. i have the following query

```
SELECT cursist FROM inschrijvingen WHERE cursus IN ('XML', 'JAV');
```

Cursist is the employeeID and inschrijvingen is basicly the Register of all courses. Now this returns all employee ID's who have been in either XML or JAVA. How would i have to check all employee's who have been in both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.  An aggregation completes your solution:

```
SELECT cursist
FROM inschrijvingen 
WHERE cursus IN ('XML', 'JAV')
GROUP BY cursist
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

If `inschrijvingen` could have duplicates, you would want `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cursus) = 2`.

Comment: Might want to use `COUNT(DISTINCT cursus)` in case there are duplicates

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT cursist
FROM inschrijvingen
WHERE cursus IN ('JAV')
    AND cursist IN (
        SELECT cursist
        FROM inschrijvingen
        WHERE cursus IN ('XML')
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be another ways using Set operator:

```
(SELECT cursist FROM inschrijvingen WHERE cursus='XML')
intersect
(SELECT cursist FROM inschrijvingen WHERE cursus='JAV');
```